# how to use mysql JDBC in h2o docker compose or docker file

Tags: mysql, docker-compose, h2o, h2o4gpu

I have to import mysql table in h2o.I am able to do this in local h2o. I need to do this at docker container.

How to use mysql JDBC(mysql connector jar) in docker compose or docker file? h2o has given only environment variables for driverlessAI. What is method or environment variables for h2o opensource?
I am using below docker compose file but its not able to pick `DRIVERLESS_AI_CONFIG_FILE` environment variable.

```
version: '3.1'

services:

  h2o:
    image: h2oai/h2o-open-source-k8s:3.32.0.3
    container_name: secure-h2o
    ports:
      - 6041:54321
    environment:
      - DRIVERLESS_AI_CONFIG_FILE: "/home/renosecure/docker-container-mount/vol-h2o/tmp/config.toml"
      - JARPATH: "/home/renosecure/docker-container-mount/vol-h2o/tmp/mysql-connector-java-8.0.23.jar"   
    volumes:
      - /home/renosecure/docker-container-mount/vol-h2o/data:/data
      - /home/renosecure/docker-container-mount/vol-h2o/log:/log
      - /home/renosecure/docker-container-mount/vol-h2o/license:/license
      - /home/renosecure/docker-container-mount/vol-h2o/tmp:/tmp
```

Answer (score 1):

H2O-3 is a Java application so it follows the usual Java way of adding to the classpath. In your example changing the environmental variable name `JARPATH` to `CLASSPATH` should work.

> I am using below docker compose file but its not able to pick DRIVERLESS_AI_CONFIG_FILE environment variable.

H2O-3 does not accept Driverless AI configuration file.